# Find max sum submatrix in 2D array/matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

Please find my current implementation below:

```
function findMaxSumSubMatrix(matrix) {
    var dim = matrix[0].length;

    // initialize prefix sum matrix
    var ps = new Array();
    for (var _ = 0; _ < dim; _++) {
        ps[_] = new Array();
    }

    // calculate vertical prefix sum matrix
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                ps[j][i] = matrix[j][i];
            } else {
                ps[j][i] = matrix[j][i] + ps[j - 1][i];
            }
        }
    }

    // console.log(ps); // log prefix sum matrix

    var maxSum = 0;
    var min, temp;

    // using the prefix sum matrix, iterate over all combinations and keep track of the max (Kadane's algorithm)
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < dim; j++) {
            min = 0;
            temp = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    temp += ps[j][k];
                } else {
                    temp += ps[j][k] - ps[i - 1][k];
                }

                if (temp < min) {
                    min = temp;
                }

                if (temp - min > maxSum) {
                    maxSum = temp - min;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return maxSum;
}


var example1 = [
    [1, -61, 5126, 612, 6],
    [41, 6, 7, 2, -7],
    [1, 73, -62, 678, 1],
    [7, -616136, 61, -83, 724],
    [-151, 6247, 872, 2517, 8135],
];

console.log(findMaxSumSubMatrix(example1)); // expected output: 18589
```

This works as expected, the output is correct.

However, I didn't write the code myself entirely.

What is unclear to me is the "min" and this part:

```
if (temp < min) {
    min = temp;
}

if (temp - min > maxSum) {
    maxSum = temp - min;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what's happening there, and why it's needed? I tried omitting it, giving incorrect results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this as a simple 1D array, where you have to find the maximum contiguous subsequence sum (exactly what Kadane's Algorithm does). For each prefix sum, you'll consider the **lowest** prefix sum that precedes it and calculate the difference (picking the lowest because you need to maximise the difference).

Similarly, the 2D array here also stores the prefix sum. We use `min` to keep a track of the lowest sum encountered in the current column. Since we need the maximum sum, we try to maximise the difference between current prefix sum (that is `temp`) and the minimum sum encountered (that is `min`).